# Trouble Loading Homebrew on macOSX

Tags: bash, homebrew, macos-sierra

To download and install Homebrew to MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 entering following in Terminal:

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install

Am receiving in response just ">". Not sure what that's telling me. Any help, please?

Comment: It means you haven't finished typing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the `)"` from the end:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`